# Get Path of local Images in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm a beginner in terms of Xamarin (Forms) and face the following problem:
I've embedded some images into the project that I can also display in the app using:

`<Image Source = 'Example.jpg'/>` (XAML or C #)

My intention now is to insert a button that selects a random image from the list for viewing.

My idea was to use a foreach loop to sort the images in an internal List .
However, I would have to know for which path the images are stored.

In a Windows Forms application I would have tried to do that with the help of

```
DirectoryInfo folderpath = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
```

This works in Xamarin Forms but unfortunately not.

Incidentally, I saved these pictures in the solution under Android / Resources / drawable. As I said, I do not get it programmatically (in the C # code) to access it.

For help in this regard, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Hi, I don't think there is any direct way to read the local image list of the project. If you want, you can create a virtual image list file, which is consistent with the local image name.

Answer (score 1):

By default A Xamarin.Forms Application searches for image inside the Resources / drawable folder in Android and in Resources for iOS. 
For example if you have 10 images to choose from, So what you can do is, name the images as 1.png, 2.png ... 10.png and store in both Android and iOS projects.
On the click on the button generate a random number between 1 to 10 and append ".png" to it and return to the image.
This would be an easier option. 
Let me know if you have queries.

Answer (score 0):

After putting your images in suitable Android/Resources/drawable and iOS/Resources folders, In C# code you can give image path like this:

`var image = new Image{Source=“example.jpg”}`